# How to do like this without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to do this without using setTimeout?

```js
    let res;
    this.auth.getUser().subscribe((response) => {
        res = response;
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(res);
    }, 1000)
```

Comment: @tkausl not working!

Comment: Move the logging into the callback of the subscription.

Comment: @pzaenger Can you explain more, please?

Comment: Try `this.auth.getUser().subscribe((response) => { res = response; console.log(res); });`

Comment: @pzaenger I need to console.log(res) outside subscribe

Comment: setInterval after clearInterval()

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  async getUser() {
    let res = await this.auth.getUser().toPromise();
    console.log(res);
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to console.log(res) outside subscribe.

Comment: update the getUser() code here and I will give another answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code :

```
>    let res;
>     this.auth.getUser().subscribe((response) => {
>       res = response;
>       console.log('Your response:', res)
>     });
```

Comment: I need to console.log(res) outside subscribe

Comment: Then make a promise based on that! @TaSvet